# filtering a list of dictionaries using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want two lists. One list giving all tickers up for the day and one list giving me all the tickers down for the day.

Given:

```
stocks = [{'ticker':'IBM', 'open': 139.50, 'close': 125.32},
          {'ticker':'NIO', 'open': 43.80, 'close': 40.30},
          {'ticker':'WMT', 'open': 134.80, 'close': 130.23},
          {'ticker':'GE', 'open': 10.13, 'close': 10.50}]
```

I have tried the following; and, it works; however, is there a better way?

```
stocks_down_list = [stocks[x]['ticker'] for x in range(len(stocks)) if stocks[x]['close'] -stocks[x]['open'] < 0]

stocks_up_list = [stocks[x]['ticker'] for x in range(len(stocks)) if stocks[x]['close'] - stocks[x]['open'] > 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Which is a "better" way could certainly be left open to interpretation, however to reduce the time complexity you could definitely consider iterating over the list of stocks once, rather than twice to build each `list` separately via a comprehension approach.

For example:

```py
stocks = [{'ticker': 'IBM', 'open': 139.50, 'close': 125.32},
          {'ticker': 'NIO', 'open': 43.80, 'close': 40.30},
          {'ticker': 'WMT', 'open': 134.80, 'close': 130.23},
          {'ticker': 'GE', 'open': 10.13, 'close': 10.50}]

stocks_up_list = []
stocks_down_list = []

for stock in stocks:
    ticker = stock['ticker']
    if stock['close'] >= stock['open']:
        stocks_up_list.append(ticker)
    else:
        stocks_down_list.append(ticker)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to only iterating through the stocks list once and more concise

```
for stock in stocks:
  (stocks_up_list, stocks_down_list)[stock['close'] < stock['open']].append(stock)
```

Comment: This is rather clever. It took me a while to understand how it works; but basically, you have a 2-element tuple which acts as a reference to the lists, and the `bool` condition allows you to "select" which list you want to append to. That is, when the condition is `True`, it will append to the second list `stocks_down_list`, since bool is a subclass of int, and True is the same as an int value of 1. Again, pretty clever.